# How to copy mysql data to azure blob using python in Azure data factory

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have followed this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-python and created the pipeline to copy data from Azure blob to blog.

Then I tried to extend this code to copy data from mysql table and store to azure blob.

I'm creating the linked services by using:

```
ls_mysql = AzureMySqlLinkedService(connection_string=mysql_string)
```

and creating dataset like this:

```
ds_azure_mysql = AzureMySqlTableDataset(ds_ls,table_name=table1)
```

And I'm getting the following exception:

> "Errors: 'AzureMySqlTable' is not a supported data set type for Azure Storage linked service. Supported types are 'AzureBlob' and 'AzureTable'"

Can you help to identify the correct method to use here? 
Or any API reference related to mysql to blob copy would really help.

Comment: You are missing an Integration Runtime. Please follow this documentation as the starting point: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-database-for-mysql as there is likely some missing Json that contain properties that are needed to make it work...

Comment: did you find a solution?